# Why is the discrete formulation of the fundamental theorem of integral calculus correct?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define Diff$_hf = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Define Av$_hf(a)=\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f$

Why is the following correct?

$\int_a^b$Diff$_hf = Avf(b) -Avf(a) $.

Comment: by the regular fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function
$$g(x):={\rm Av}_hf(x)={1\over h}\int_x^{x+h} f(t)\>dt\ .$$
Then $$g'(x)={1\over h}\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)={\rm Diff}_hf(x)\ .$$
It follows that
$${\rm Av}_hf(b)-{\rm Av}_hf(a)=g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^b g'(x)\>dx=\int_a^b{\rm Diff}_hf(x)\>dx\ .$$